# Sufficient conditions on $ a_i,b_i$ for $a_1\phi(n)+b_1, \cdots, a_k\phi(n)+b_k$ to be simultaneously prime infinitely often?

Tags: prime-numbers, arithmetic-progression, prime-number-theorem, estimation-theory

I am really interested in sufficient conditions on $a_i, b_i$ guaranteeing that the linear forms  $a_1\phi(n)+b_1,\dots, a_k\phi(n)+b_k$ become simultaneously prime for infinitely many positive integers $n$. Here, $\phi(n)$ is the Euler's totient function and $a_i, b_i$ are arbitrary positive  integers.

**Background.**  In the 1904 paper  of L. E. Dickson titled  *A new extension of Dirichlet’s theorem on prime numbers, Messenger of Math. 33 (1904), 155–161*, 
the problem of if the forms $a_1 n+b_1 ,\cdots ,a_kn+b_k$ become simultaneously prime infinitely many times is discussed (See [Dickson's Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson%27s_conjecture).) In my question here $n$ is replaced with $\phi(n)$.

**Note**: The motivation of this question is the estimation of primes using Euler's toitient function and also to know if there is any connection between Lucas-Lehmer Primality test and the titled affine-linear form for $d=1$ and $t=1$ because the latter depend on relationship between $n$ and $\phi(n)$

Comment: I find even the problem of constructing an infinite family of pairs $(a,b)$ with the property that each linear form $a\phi(n)+b$ becomes prime for infinitely many values of $n$ hard. The only example of such a form I have is $\phi(n)+1$ where $a=b=1$; its value is prime once $n$ is. But for instance, if you want to use the same approach to argue that the pairs $\phi(n)+1,\phi(n)-1$ or $\phi(n)+1,2\phi(n)+3$ become simultaneously prime infinitely often, you arrive at unsolved conjectures such as the infinitude of twin primes or Germain primes.

Comment: @KhashF this question was upvoted and now it downvoted however it received good answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most probably $\gcd(a_i,b_i)=1$ and $a_i \geq 1$ and $b_i$ to be odd  for $i=1,...,k$ is enough.

Since $\{\varphi(n): n \in \mathbb N\}$ can be partitioned into countably many subsets $C_l=\{\varphi(w_{rl}): r \in \mathbb N\}$ such that $\varphi(w_{ml})<\varphi(w_{nl})$ if $m<n$ the $k$ forms $a_j \cdot \varphi(n) +b_j$ for $j=1,...,k$ are all prime for an infinite number of values of $n$ if they are:

a) prime for at least one $r$ for every $l$

b) prime for an infinite number of $r$˙s for some $l$

The b) leads to research of subsequences of $\mathbb N$ such that Dickson´s conjecture is true for those subsequences, and, I think that even in the case $k=1$ that is not fully resolved.

In other words, the necessary and sufficient conditions for a subsequence $s_{\alpha(i)}$ of $\mathbb N$ to give an infinite number of primes $as_{\alpha(i)}+b$ for $\gcd(a,b)=1$ can be stated, but the generalization of Dirichlet´s theorem given in this form, is, I think, not yet available anywhere, in other words, not proven anywhere.

And you ask even more, that is, slight modification of generalization of Dickson´s conjecture, and, there is not much that can be surely told about that, since even the Dickson´s conjecture is unsolved.